# Find the nth top-level category in a nav tag

Tags: categories

I want to output some code after the 10th **top level** category in a category listing. For example...

- 1.

  - 1.1.
  - 1.2.
- 2.

  - 2.1.
- 3.
- ...
- 10.
- Zoiks!

The problem is, I can't use Twig's loop.index in a conditional because it counts each of the children too (like a flat list). How can I test for the 10th top-level category?

```
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('categoryGroup') %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
    {% ifchildren %}
      <ul>
        {% children %}
      </ul>
    {% endifchildren %}
  </li>
  {% if category.level == 1 and loop.index == 10 %}
    <li>Zoiks! That‘s a lot of categories!</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endnav %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll just need to put it *before* the `{% children %}` tags.  Something like:

```
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('categoryGroup') %}
    <li>

        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>

        {% if category.level == 1 and loop.index == 10 %}
            <li>Zoiks! That‘s a lot of categories!</li>
        {% endif %}

        {% if category.level == 1 %}
            {% set topLevelIndex = topLevelIndex + 1 %}
        {% endif %}

        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
                {% children %}
            </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks, I thought I was going crazy. Is there are reason putting it before the `{% children %}` tag works?

Comment: `{% children %}` is where things start to get recursive behind the scenes so variable scoping comes into play and `topLevelIndex` never gets updated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can add in a little counting magic of your own:

```
{# before the nav tag #}
{% set topLevelIndex = 1 %}

{# inside nav loop #}
{% if category.level == 1 and topLevelIndex == 10 %}
    <li>Zoiks! That‘s a lot of categories!</li>
{% endif %}
{% if category.level == 1 %}
    {% set topLevelIndex = topLevelIndex + 1 %}
{% endif %}
```

*This code hasn't been tested...*

Comment: That's the workaround I tried initially, but topLevelIndex never goes past 2. I tested it by putting `{{ topLevelIndex }}` right after trying to increment it. I have `set topLevelIndex = 1` outside the nav tag and `set topLevelIndex = topLevelIndex + 1` is inside the nav tag loop.

Comment: I think this might be a bug with the nav tag. If I try the same counter method using a for loop instead of the nav tag, it works as expected.

Comment: Aha. Maybe someone from P&T can explain that better for us :)